Setting tempo in the pygame.midi package
I'm trying to find a way to set the tempo of music when using the
pygame.midi package. I found a suggestion of code, and tried it.
import pygame.midi
from time import sleep

pygame.midi.init()  # Initialize the Midi module
player = pygame.midi.Output(0)  # Attach to the output device (speakers)

tempo = 600000  # 100 BPM

player.write_short(0xFF, 0x51, 0x03)  # Meta message for tempo change
player.write_short(tempo >> 16)
player.write_short(tempo >> 8 & 0xFF)
player.write_short(tempo & 0xFF)

tempo_message = [0xFF, 0x51, 0x03, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x7A, 0x1F]

player.write(tempo_message)

but I'm receiving this error

Exception: b"PortMidi: `Invalid MIDI message Data'"

Has anyone had any experience in making this work? Thanks.
This is the full traceback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\klynn\PycharmProjects\gems2024\musictemplate.py", line 14, in <module>
    player.write_short(tempo >> 16)
  File "C:\Users\klynn\PycharmProjects\gems2024\venv\lib\site-packages\pygame\midi.py", line 516, in write_short
    self._output.WriteShort(status, data1, data2)
  File "src_c\\cython\\pygame\\pypm.pyx", line 478, in pygame.pypm.Output.WriteShort
Exception: b"PortMidi: `Invalid MIDI message Data'"


Could you post the complete traceback of the error you are getting?

Can you explain why you're writing the bytes that you're writing, with a reference to the MIDI spec that you've based that on? Because tempo is the three tempo op code bytes, and then three more bytes for the number of microseconds per quarter note. Your first block of code shows you writing six instead of three bytes, and the second block shows you writing five bytes instead of three.

To be honest, I'm not sure. I found this particular code in reference to the problem and tried it out, but there wasn't much documentation
